# prevent opening any page if user not logged in

Tags: php, forms

my web application consists of 2 pages (Log in page , Main page)

i want to prevent the user from viewing main page if the user did not logged in before so i do the following :

in Main page i check for username session which is set in login authentication

```
  session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS'])||$_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS']!=true) {
        header('Location:login.php?lang=en');
        exit();
    }
```

Now : when i open the main page i redirected to login screen which is right , but when i log in then logout then try to login again i redirected to login page also and cannot login again

in logout :

```
session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    $lang=$_SESSION['lang'];
    unset($_SESSION['lang']);
    session_unset();
    if(session_destroy()){
        header("Location: login.php?lang=$lang");
        exit;

}
```

java script login code :

```
$(function () {
    var form = $('#main form'),
            arrow = $('#main .arrow');
    $('#main .row input').val('');

    function submitLogin(enteredUsername, enteredPassword) {
        $.ajax({
            url: './webService/CheckLogin.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {username: enteredUsername, password: enteredPassword},
            cache: false,
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp.toString() === "true") {
                    window.location = 'Main.php';
                } else {
                    // fail code here.
                    alert("Login Failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // Handle form submissions
    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
        submitLogin(user, pass);
    });
});
```

check Login.php

```
 require("./DbConnection.php");
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
        $username = ($_POST['username']);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
        $password = ($_POST['password']);
    }
    AuthenticateUser($username, $password);
    function AuthenticateUser($username, $password) {
        $conn = OpenConnection();
        $tsql = "select userName,Password from Users ";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
        if ($stmt === false) {
            echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
            if ($username == $row[0] && $password == $row[1]) {
                $res = 'true';
                $_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS']=true;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                break;
            } else {
                $res = 'FALSE';      
            }
        }
        CloseConnection($stmt, $conn);
        echo $res;
    }
```

Comment: Although i'm not directly answering you, you should always include session_start() on every page you want to have a session.

Comment: What is login.php Code?

Comment: There's likely something going wrong in `login.php`; what does that code do?  You also don't need (or generally want) to destroy the session.  Here's a similar [page lock script](http://www.digitalgemstones.com/code/tools/auth/lock.php) I wrote a long time ago.

Comment: What do you mean by; 'Cannot login again' ? Does it give any errors?

Comment: i already include session_start() on every page.

Comment: i cannot login again as it redirected me to login page again instead of login normally and open main page

Comment: show your login page code.

Comment: I notice that the main.php script redirects to the login.page. However, the login.php doesn't redirect if successful. How are you gettting to see the main page after a successful login?

Comment: i include the java script login code in lgoin page and i redirect to main screen if successful as shown above :   
           window.location = 'Main.php';

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Dont include the session on your login screen.

Comment: i can't execlude session from login screen , i uses session variables in login screen to pass some variable to the next screen (main screen)